# Why are two array clones are mimicking each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Note: I have left the original variable names intact as reference to the original code at the bottom of this post.

If I try to reproduce in chromes console then I don't see my error happening...

example simplified without layers of arrays:

```
var c = [0,1,2,3];

var CC = [c.slice(0),c.slice(0)];

var xA = -1;

CC[0] = [xA].concat(CC[0].slice(0,CC[0].length-1));
```

This produces two arrays the first is the original the second has the number -1 at the start and is missing the number 3 from the end. It also leaves the original untouched.

Like so:

```
c= [0,1,2,3];
CC=[
   [-1,0,1,2],
   [ 0,1,2,3]
];
```

The problem is that when I attempt do do this in a more complicated environment the two arrays inside the CC array act as if they are deep copied (If I change one then the other also changes). I think what is happening is that I am cloning the c Array but all of the arrays it holds are only references to the original..

**The Complicated Environment**

I have an array (c) with arrays inside, the inner arrays each hold one extra array and three values as a collection. the structure is as follows:

```
var c=[[extraArray1,value1,value2,value3],[extraArray2,value1,value2,value3],...];
```

I try to make two clones of the array c into a temporary array (CC) of two as I intend to slightly alter the extraArrays of the clone at index zero (this is so later on I can begin running through all the arrays and compare )

```
var CC=[c.slice(0),c.slice(0)]; //the first clone will be slightly altered
```

There is no way I can JSFiddel this as it is way too large and too much data. I have isolated the code beneath and also checked and checked again my Array objects and they look as expected!

```
xA[13]=11.11111; // some number for the sake of this post
console.log(CC[0][13][0].indexOf(xA[13]));
// -1
console.log(CC[1][13][0].indexOf(xA[13]));
// -1

CC[0][13][0]=[xA[13]].concat(CC[0][13][0].slice(0,CC[0][13][0].length-1));
console.log(CC[0][13][0].indexOf(xA[13]));
// 0
console.log(CC[1][13][0].indexOf(xA[13]));
// 0
```

If I alter `CC[0][13][0]` then why does `CC[1][13][0]` also alter?

Comment: `.slice` only performs a **shallow copy**. It simply creates a new array and puts all values of the original array in there. You seem to be looking for **deep copying / cloning**. https://www.google.com/search?q=deep%20copy%20javascript

Comment: splice seems to destroy the original array

Comment: @8DK What does that have to do with it? You're not using `splice`.

Comment: `.splice` is for mutating the array *in place*. It allows you do add and remove elements. It has nothing to do with copying.

Comment: "two arrays inside the CC array act as if they are deep copied (If I change one then the other also changes)..." that is the opposite of a deep copy.

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));


It is very odd that arrays don't have a simple prototype for this!

Comment: Look into the ***Description*** section at the first note ***For object references...*** **[Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**, you'll see it matches your complex example where `array` is actually an object reference. While in the simple example, the elements are just numbers, so copying value is performed.

Comment: Can someone put an answer so for the sake of this site I can accept and this *open* issue will be solved